# MISRA 2008: Cannot understand 5-0-13 rule

Tags: c++, misra

I cannot understand 5-0-13 rule itself:

> **Rule 5-0-13:** The condition of an if-statement and the condition of an iteration-statement shall have type bool.
>
> **Rationale:** If an expression with type other than bool is used in the condition of an if-statement or iteration-statement, then its result will be implicitly converted to bool. The condition expression shall contain an explicit test (yielding a result of type bool) in order to clarify the intentions of the developer.
>
> **Exception:** A condition of the form type-specifier-seq declarator is not required to have type bool.
> This exception is introduced because alternative mechanisms for achieving the same effect are cumbersome and error-prone.
>
> ```
> extern int32_t * fn ( );
> extern int32_t fn2 ( );
> extern bool fn3 ( );
> while ( int32_t * p = fn ( ) ) // Compliant by exception
> {
>  // Code
> }
> // The following is a cumbersome but compliant example
> do
> {
>  int32_t * p = fn ( );
>  if ( NULL == p )
>  {
>  break;
>  }
>  // Code...
> }
> while ( true ); // Compliant
> while ( int32_t length = fn2 ( ) ) // Compliant by exception
> {
>  // Code
> }
> while ( bool flag = fn3 ( ) ) // Compliant
> {
>  // Code
> }
> if ( int32_t * p = fn ( ) ) // Compliant by exception
> if ( int32_t length = fn2 ( ) ) // Compliant by exception
> if ( bool flag = fn3 ( ) ) // Compliant
> if ( u8 ) // Non-compliant
> if ( u8 && ( bool_1 <= bool_2 ) ) // Non-compliant
> for ( int32_t x = 10; x; --x ) // Non-compliant
> ```

... And how is it different from

> **Rule 5-3-1:** Each operand of the ! operator, the logical && or the logical || operators shall have type *bool*
>
> **Rationale:** The use of operands with types other than bool with these operators is unlikely to be meaningful (or intended). This rule allows the detection of such uses, which often occur because the logical operators (&&, || and !) can be easily confused with the bitwise operators (&, | and ~).
>
> ```
> if ( ( a < b ) && ( c < d ) ) // Compliant
> if ( 1 && ( c < d ) ) // Non-compliant
> if ( ( a < b ) && ( c + d ) ) // Non-compliant
> if ( u8_a && ( c + d ) ) // Non-compliant
> if ( !0 ) // Non-compliant –
>  // also breaks other rules
> if ( !ptr ) // Non-compliant
> if ( !false ) // Compliant with this rule,
>  // but breaks others
> ```

Comment: Seems quite clear to me, it really would help someone answer your question if you explained what it is you don't understand. I'd be surprised if anyone is willing to go through the text line by line for you.

Comment: PS I don't agree with the exception, but it's only an opinion.

Comment: Rule 5-3-1 applies to the operands of the logical operators, rule 5-0-13 applies to the conditions of if statements etc. These are different things, so I'm not sure what you mean whan you ask what is the difference.

Comment: PPS @john I agree with your disagreement. In fact, many (most) compilers will warn about use of code like `while ( int32_t * p = fn ( ) )...`

Comment: I guess they could've combined 5-3-1 and 5-0-13 into one rule that says "in any context that expects a boolean, only boolean expressions are allowed". That would then also cover things like `bool x = ptr` and `function_taking_boolean(c + d)`.

Comment: @john When all operands of the condition are bools, the whole condition will be bool as well, right? This is why I don't understand the necessity of 5-0-13. Yeah, my question is **far** from being good, sorry. When we start to learn new things, it's not uncommon to ask nonsense.

Comment: @john I prefer `if (T * ptr = try_get()) { ... }` over `{ T * ptr = try_get(); if (bool{ptr}) { ... } }` over `T * ptr = try_get(); if (bool{ptr}) { ... }`. Not leaking into the surrounding scope is worth an implicit conversion.

Comment: This is probably inherited from MISRA-C. And in the C language, boolean expressions such as the result of the logical operators are actually type `int`, unlike in C++ where they are of type `bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule 5-3-1 also applies outside `if`, `while` and `for`, e.g.

```
extern void set_flag(bool);

set_flag( ( a < b ) && ( c < d ) ); // Compliant
set_flag( 1 && ( c < d ) ); // Non-compliant
set_flag( ( a < b ) && ( c + d ) ); // Non-compliant
set_flag( u8_a && ( c + d ) ); // Non-compliant
set_flag( !0 ) // Non-compliant –
 // also breaks other rules
set_flag( !ptr ); // Non-compliant
set_flag( !false ); // Compliant with this rule,
 // but breaks others

bool one = ( ( a < b ) && ( c < d ) ); // Compliant
bool two = ( 1 && ( c < d ) ); // Non-compliant
bool three = ( ( a < b ) && ( c + d ) ); // Non-compliant
bool four = ( u8_a && ( c + d ) ); // Non-compliant
bool five = ( !0 ); // Non-compliant –
 // also breaks other rules
bool six = ( !ptr ); // Non-compliant
bool seven = ( !false ); // Compliant with this rule,
 // but breaks others
```

Answer (score 1):

The ***rule 5-0-13*** states that any statement inside the 'if' condition will be treated as something that results in a boolean value only.

This rule is meant for the purpose of ***dealing with the common problem of missing = in if conditions***

I.E., to handle the scenario in which the programmer had written an assignment statement instead of a comparison statement.

**Here is the explanation by an example:**

Imagine that a programmer had made a typing mistake in the 'if' condition and missed the required extra '='.

I.E.,

Instead of doing

```
if (x == 0) { 
  // Do something when value of x is zero
}
```

the programmer had written:

```
if (x = 0) {
  // Do something after assgining x to 0
}
```

**The above error can cause bugs that are easy to be introduced but very difficult to be identified**

The rule 5-0-13 states that the assignment statement (x = 0) will be executed and the result of the statement will be evaluated for the condition.

Therefore, as per this rule, (x = 0) will be performed and the statements inside the loop will be executed if the assignment (x = 0) was successful.